# Visual Studio unable to include plugin from Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-2015

I developing an app in Cordova, Visual Studio 2015 and I have previous dowloades and sucessfull included [BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) and [Phonegap-nfc](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/tree/master/src) throw the config.xml file. But now when I tried whit [tedious](https://github.com/tedious/tedious.github.io) I get this error error:

> Plugin downloaded from URL: https://github.com/tedious/tedious.github.io

I have tried to downloading the zip file and include it throw local. Also this time throw config.xml. but I got this error message:

> Visual studio was unable to parse plugin.xml. Please ensure plugin.xml exist and contains no error.

The plugin.xml exist and I can't find any error. How do I solve this? Or is there a better way to connect my cordova app whit Mssql?

Comment: First you gotta say what plugin it is, from which link you tried to install. Noone will be able to help you out with such minimal data

Comment: I have done some update in my question, as you told my too.

Comment: First of all, its not a cordova plugin at all. I dont see any plugin.xml file in this. How are you installing this plugin?

Comment: @Thuder_Lord79 Any update on this? you can only include cordova plugins.

Comment: OKey, do you have any solution on how I can connect my app to my mssql database?

Comment: @Thuder_Lord79 You gotta first build a webservice first to connect to  mssql server and you can invoke the webservice fron cordova app through AJAX calls. Check out this link

Comment: Posted the answer. Please accept if it was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only cordova plugins can be included by the way you followed in Visual Studio. The plugin needs to have plugin.xml file which contains plugin id and other details related to the plugin.Phonegap nfc and barcode scanner were cordova plugins which contains plugin.xml. Hence you were able to add the same in VS.

But the plugin which failed to add - https://github.com/tedious/tedious.github.io is not a cordova plugin and it does not have plugin.xml. Hence you will not be able to add the same in VS